# Javascript Base64 decode using a reverse loop?

Tags: javascript, base64

According to this: http://jsperf.com/fors-vs-while/15  running loops in reverse in javascript yield much faster results.  Has anyone heard of or tried decoding Base64 strings using javascript in reverse?

Comment: Don't get sucked into a performance fallacy here. The only two comparable tests relevant to forward vs. reverse I can see on that page are *"for loop, cached length"* and *"for loop, reversed"*. And these two loops are virtually identical in performance. The other loops are all doing vastly different things and hardly allow any decision to be made about whether a "forward" or "reverse" loop is faster.

Comment: reverse is supposed to be faster since it's comparing to false rather than an integer. These are micro-optimizations though

Answer (score 0):

The algorithm would be something like :

```
   1. Pad the input string to a multiple of 3 characters
   2. Initialize an empty results array 
   3. Looping backwards in the input string taking 3 chars at a time
   4.    convert 3 chars to the 4 Base64 equivalent
   5.    unshift the Base64 string to the results array
   6. Return the join of the results array.
```